# DataGrid HasItems is false when Items.Count > 0 why?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, itemscontrol

I have a `DataGrid`. I am loading the `DataGrid` from `ViewModel` and `ItemSource` is `Binded` to a `ViewModel property`. When i click on an item in a `TreeView` and based on the `TreeViewItem` i am changing the collection for the `DataGrid` from ViewModel and raising the `PropertyChanged`. i have a condition which checks for `DataGrid HasItems` in an `AttachedProperty's` CoerceValueCallBack and it returns `false`, but the same time i checked with the `Items.Count > 0` yes its greater than 0.

From MSDN

> ItemsControl.HasItems Property
>
> `true if the items count is greater than 0; otherwise, false.The default is false.`

I am wondering why `HasItems` returns false and `Items.Count` is greater than zero ?

My attached property

```
 public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
         "IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(EDataGridCellFocus),
         new UIPropertyMetadata(false, null, OnCoerceValue));
private static object OnCoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        if (((DataGrid)d).HasItems) // (((DataGrid)d).Items.Count > 0) is true but (((DataGrid)d).HasItems) is false 
        { 
             //Some Code
        }
    }
```

This attached property is used to set the `keyboard focus` of the Grid when i Tab on my `TreeViewItem`.

`TreeView` and my `DataGrid` are in two different `UserControl`.

My DataGrid

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfDocuments}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDocument,Mode=TwoWay}" 
              SelectionMode="Single"
              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              IsReadOnly="True" 
              RowHeight="25" 
              CanUserAddRows="False" 
              utility:EDataGridCellFocus.IsFocused="{Binding IsGridFocused}">
```

My collection,

```
 public List<DocumentModel> ListOfDocuments
    {
        get { return _ListOdDocuments; }
        set { _ListOdDocuments = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Adding item to my collection,

```
 if(ListOfDocuments==null)
    {
       ListOfDocuments = new List<DocumentModel>();
    }
 ListOfDocuments.Clear();
 foreach (var item in DocumentsFromDataBase)
 {
     ListOfDocuments.Add(item);//item is kind of DocumentModel
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Well, at least the solution seems clear. How big is Items.Count actually?  Whe it's 1 it could be something with the AutoAdd ghost row. Otherwise it's some refresh problem.

Comment: items count is 5 and more not more than 15.

Comment: @HenkHolterman if refresh is the problem why is items count showing up. i am not sure where to do refresh for a `DataGrid` binded with `ItemSource`

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange to see them different. `HasItems` is not simply implemented as `Items.Count > 0`. In fact `HasItems` is resolved after `Items` is changed.
So if you do anything in between the time when `Items` is changed and the time before `HasItems` is resolved, you will see they are different.

By looking in the source code of `ItemsControl`, you'll see that `HasItems` is actually a wrapper of `HasItemsProperty` and defined like this:

```
[Bindable(false), Browsable(false)]
public bool HasItems {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(HasItemsProperty); }
}
```

The `HasItemsProperty` is updated only in the collection changed handler of `Items`, here it is in the source code:

```
((INotifyCollectionChanged)_items).CollectionChanged += 
        new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(OnItemCollectionChanged2);
//the handler
private void OnItemCollectionChanged2(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){
        SetValue(HasItemsPropertyKey, (_items != null) && !_items.IsEmpty);   
        ...
}
```

So as you see, they are not in sync. It would be more helpful if you let us know what your attached property (mentioned in your question) is.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the use of my Attached Property and code. please have a look. the attached property raise the `CoerceValueCallBack ` only when i press `Tab` from my `TreeView`

Comment: @AbinMathew I can see that property is bound to `IsGridFocused`, so when that property could be changed? Also it's not clear on how you add item to your dataGrid via TreeView here.

Comment: `IsGridFocused` getting changed on `Tab`, Adding item to `DataGrid` by clearing the `ItemSource` here its `ListOfDocuments` is a List. added the code in the question.

Comment: @AbinMathew so after adding items you press Tab to focus on DataGrid? If so that's strange because although `HasItems` does not sync with `Items.Count` tightly but they are very close in a sequence of events (adding -> collection changed).

Comment: Yes after adding items i press Tab to focus on DataGrid, Its strange but i can check with my Items.Count but looks ugly and HasItems property now it has now role :( Thanks for good explanation.